# Minor mode for editing ansible playbooks

Tags: indentation

I have recently started using ansible, and `yaml-mode` seemed the logical choice for editing playbooks. However, the indentation does not quite work correctly. For example, I might start a task definition like so:

```
- name: install packages
```

Adding the next line, it needs to be indented as follows:

```
- name: install packages
  apt: name=emacs24 state=present
```

However, what `yaml-mode` wants to do is:

```
- name: install packages
    apt: name=emacs24 state=present
```

If I tab again:

```
- name: install packages
apt: name=emacs24 state=present
```

In other words, in order to get the correct indentation, I need to manually enter the correct number of spaces instead of using the tab key. **Is there a mode where I can get the correct behavior, or a way to configure `yaml-mode` to do what I want?** Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the latest yaml-mode version.  Please try upgrading your version and if the error still persists, hand in a bug.

Comment: @wasamasa I am on the most recent version through MELPA. Which version are you on (for me, `yaml-mode-version` returns `0.0.12`)?

Comment: 0.0.12 is the latest tag, however there have been several commits since that.  MELPA unstable should have a build incorporating them, are you possibly on MELPA stable?

Comment: @wasamasa Argggg...I am on unstable, but I just tried starting Emacs with `-Q` and I have the desired behavior...This has been happening a  lot to me recently. I always tell people to try `-Q`, but rarely think to try it myself before asking a question...I guess I will get to bisecting my init once again, haha

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/k1LoW/emacs-ansible

will highlight keywords.

https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides

promises to highlight indent levels, even shows a nice video of it, but I had trouble getting it working

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Does this help with entering indentation/reindenting?  Could you perhaps post a screen shot?

Comment: If you visit that 2nd URL, there's a nice video showing what is supposed to happen - vertical lines should appear that show the current indentation level, and one dynamically highlights as you move the point, to show the current indent level. For me, even though the h-i-g minor mode is active, it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Yes, but external links tend to die.  Including something directly in the answer will make it more useful in the future.